# What kind of power plug does the ICOM IC-7300 need?

Tags: icom

I am considering buying the IC-7300. What kind of connector will I need to connect it to an external power supply? Or, does it come with a connector that I can splice on to a power cable coming from the DC power supply?

For instance, will I need something like this adaptor?
https://www.gigaparts.com/powerwerx-hf4-pp.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A new IC-7300 comes with the power harness that plugs into the radio. The other end is connectorless so you can adapt it to your power supply using lugs, PowerPoles, stripped ends, etc.

Comment: @MarqTwine You are welcome. Enjoy the new radio!

Comment: A perhaps useful note: The EU version of the radio, comes with a filter installed on the power cable, near the connector for the radio. This filter additionally has a relatively short ground wire which needs to be connected to the radio's chassis ground screw. The filter itself is a bit bulky and has very pointed edges, which might complicate installation in some cases.